# iPhone mic transmit to earpiece?

Tags: iphone, microphone, ear-phones

I am deaf in one ear and have trouble conversing in a noisy restaurant. I am looking for a way to place my iPhone 5 on the table in front of my partner so that the sound picked up by its built-in microphone is transmitted to an earphone I would wear. Suggestions ?

Comment: iOS 12 supports this right out of the box, but this requires at least an iPhone 5S.

Comment: Thanks. I am about to install iOS 12 on my iPad, so could try it on that. Can you point me to a page in the manual ? Otherwise I will have to queue for hours at my local Genius Bar....

Comment: I‘ll add an answer later

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Mimi Music app, which has that feature. The App Store page lists iOS 9 as the minimum requirement, so there's a good chance it will run.

Comment: Thanks. Mimi Music is an interesting app but as far as I can tell it works on audio file input, not mic-sourced real-time input.

Comment: Well, it _used_ to have that feature. Apparently it has been removed, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

iOS12 supports this out of the box, and apparently it even works with AirPods. Apple has a [support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203990) with all the details online.

But with AirPods it’s even [easier](https://www.imangoss.net/2018/06/live-listen-feature-ios-12/):

**Enable it in Control Center**

- Settings -> Control Center -> Customize Controls
- Tap (+) on Hearing

Now access Control Center by swiping up from the bottom of the screen and you will see an icon with an Ear

**How to Use Live Listen Feature in iOS 12**

- Pair and put on your Airpods in to your Ear
- Access Control Center
- Tap the Hearing Sign
- Tap On & Done